# MvvmCross MvxCommand Documentation

Tags: mvvmcross

Near the bottom of page https://www.mvvmcross.com/documentation/fundamentals/value-converters
the `CommandParameter` option of the `MvxBind` command is discussed. 
The code snippet:
`new MvxCommand(day => DoAction(day));`
generates a compile-time error "Delegate 'Action' does not take 1 arguments".
Should this example be:
`new MvxCommand<String>(day => DoAction(day));`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it should be. When specifying a generic parameter, `MvxCommand<T>(DoAction)` Implies that specified delegate method `DoAction` takes a parameter of type T.